# ¿Cuál es el significado de unsigned en C++?

Tags: c++, c

Tratando de recordar C++. Cuando tengo por ejemplo, esta función:

```
std::vector<unsigned> nombreDefuncion(unsigned m){...
         unsigned i;
         std::vector<unsigned> lista(m);
         for(....){...}
         return lista
}
```

¿A qué se refiere `unsigned`? El código es solo un ejemplo.

Gracias!

Comment: `unsigned` y `unsigned int` significan la misma cosa, y es un tipo de datos que sólo almacenará enteros positivos o cero, nunca negativos.

Comment: Una historia divertida. Unix guarda la hora mediante un unsigned int, que cuenta el número de segundos transcurridos desde el 1 de enero de 1970. En el unsigned int el número mayor que cabe es el  4.294.967.295. Cuando hayan transcurrido ese número de segundos (lo que ocurrirá el 19 de enero 2038) ese sistema ya no podrá seguir usándose pues al sumar 1 al máximo se vuelve a cero (un nuevo "efecto 2000"). Si el número hubiera sido `int` (sin `unsigned`) se habría agotado hace ya tiempo y además en vez de pasar a cero al desbordar, se iría a los negativos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Completando la respuesta de @Yeste `unsigned` se refiere al signo. Si un entero es declarado con `unsigned int` quiere decir que por defecto ese número es entero ya que no se almacena su signo (unsigned).

Los enteros (`int`) en **C++** tienen 32 bits, el primer bit siempre corresponde al signo de dicho entero, de tal forma que te quedan 31 bits para almacenar el número. Con un `unsigned int` no se tiene en cuenta el signo, puesto que se considera positivo, por lo que tienes 32 bits para guardar el número. Esto hace que el rango que pueden tomar las variables varie:

- El rango de un `int` va de -2.147.483.648 a 2.147.483.647.
- El rango de un `unsigned int` va de 0 to 4.294.967.295

Como puedes ver, al ahorrar el signo puedes guardar números más grandes, ya que puedes guardar una mayor cantidad de información. Si intentamos guardar un int con mayor cantidad de información soportada por el tipo de dato, fallará, aquí un ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n = 3147483647;
    cout<< n;

    return 0;
}
```

#### ALERTA

Una vez conocido todo esto, lo normal es usar `int`, es un error sobre todo por personas que se inician en el lenguaje querer usarlo para aumentar el rango, o intentar restrigir/verificar números negativos. El propio Bjarne Stroustrup (Creador de C++) comentó al respecto:

> Using an unsigned instead of an int to gain one more bit to represent positive integers is almost never a good idea

*sección 4.4; pag 75; libro "The C++ Programming Language"*

Que en Español viene a decir, que casi nunca es una buena idea usarlos con la intención de ganar 1 bit más.

**¿Entonces cuando hay que usarlos?**
Hay algunos casos en los que es completamente necesario, o no te queda otra opción:

- Cuando realizas manipulaciones con bits (bit manipulation)
- Algún programa o librería que es necesario usarlos por como ha sido desarrollada.
- Cuando tratas con sistemas que tienen procesos/memoria limitada, el uso de `unsigned` es más común por razones de rendimiento.

Comment: Revisa la respuesta. En algunos lugares dices "bits" cuando querías decir "bytes".

Comment: Toda la razón @abulafia Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya lo he cambiado!

Comment: De nada, pero ahora has cambiado un bit por byte, que tenía que quedarse como bit. El de signo :-) Igual vale más que digas que son 32 bits, 1 de signo y otros 31 para el valor

Comment: Sí, finalmente lo he cambiado todo a **bits**, porque era lioso hasta para mí estar alternando entre bytes y bits, jaja. Creo que así se entiende mejor la respuesta.

Comment: *El propio Bjarne Stroustrup (Creador de C++) comentó al respecto...* podrias agregar la fuente en la respuesta?

Comment: He editado la respuesta con la cita! Supongo que la página exacta puede que varie dependiendo de la edición.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando usas `unsigned` sin ningún añadido estás realmente llamando a `unsigned int` .
La diferencia entre signed y unsigned int es que en un integer de 32 bits, el unsigned integer tiene un rango de 0 a 2^32 -1 mientras que el signed int va desde -2^31 a 2^31. Por tanto, esto quiere decir que la representación de números negativos debe ser con signed int mientras que la de exclusivamente positivos puede ser con unsigned.